# How do I make Emacs recognize bash environment variables for compilation?

Tags: emacs, compilation

I'm trying to compile u-boot via Emacs' compilation mode, and it looks like Emacs doesn't know how to find bash environment variables. Even though I set them, and can compile via Emacs shell emulation, compilation mode still tries to compile as if they aren't there.

What do I need to do to make it more environment conscious?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can try adding something like to your `.emacs`:

```
(let ((path (shell-command-to-string ". ~/.bashrc; echo -n $PATH")))
  (setenv "PATH" path)
  (setq exec-path 
        (append
         (split-string-and-unquote path ":")
         exec-path)))
```

Depending on whether you've set the env variables in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` you might need to slightly adjust this snippet. The example is for the `PATH` variable, which is a bit more special (since you have to set `exec-path` in Emacs as well), but can be extended to work for arbitrary variables - you could have a list of variables that have to be read from `.bashrc` and set into Emacs.

I'm not sure whether you're using OS X or GNU/Linux. Starting Emacs from the GUI's menu-bar in Linux will typically result in an Emacs that does not have the same `PATH` as one launched from the command line. This problem dates back to the first `xdm` Xsession scripts, and while they are fairly easy to fix (basically use an `Xsessionwrapper` script that does `exec $SHELL -c Xsession` so the shell gets run before running the user's Xsession), nobody has bother to do so in a very long time (and I doubt that anyone will). As far as I know the problem is present even into moder xdm descendants such as `kdm` and `gdm`.

On OS X the handling of the env variables is another problem entirely and to get your ENV variables you typically have to run Emacs from the command line like this `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` or play with `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`. The code snippet I've provided should cover you in both cases though.

**Update**

Recently this process was made easier by the [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) extension. It sets the emacs `$PATH` in more or less the same manner, but using an extension is generally preferable to hacking the solution yourself.

Comment: This resolve my issue with Flymake not using the correct Perl from perlbrew. Unlike perlbrew-mini.el

Comment: _exec-path-from-shell_ is great and resolved my issue with _ensime_ which couldn't start and throw `wrong type argument stringp nil` error.

Comment: Why do you use split-string-and-unquote instead of split-string?

Comment: Although the answer is clear on this, for anyone skimming quickly, the first two lines in this answer were what I was searching for:
(let ((MYVAR (shell-command-to-string ". ~/.bashrc; echo -n $MYVAR")))
  (setenv "MYVAR" MYVAR))

Comment:  this solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This is where the environment variables of the process that started `emacs` are:

> — Command: **getenv var**
>
> This function returns the value of the
>   environment variable var, as a string. var should be a string. If var
>   is undefined in the environment, getenv returns nil. It returns ‘""’
>   if var is set but null. Within Emacs, a list of environment variables
>   and their values is kept in the variable process-environment.
>
> ```
>       (getenv "USER")
>            ⇒ "lewis"
> ```
>
> — Variable: **process-environment**
>
> This variable is a list of strings,
>   each describing one environment variable. The functions getenv and
>   setenv work by means of this variable.
>
> ```
>       process-environment
>       ⇒ ("PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
>           "USER=lewis"
>           "TERM=xterm"
>           "SHELL=/bin/bash"
>           "HOME=/home/lewis"
>           ...)
> ```

You seem to be assuming that emacs was started from a **bash** session. However, often processes under X are started from an **sh** session, which would **not** read the environment variables you had set in your `~/.bashrc` script. One simple way to circumvent this is to change your `~/.xinitrc` file to use **bash** instead of **sh** (it could be as simple as adding `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the file).

Source: [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/System-Environment.html)

Comment: Did you mean `#!/bin/bash`?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't strictly answer your question, but you can always pass environment variables on the `make` command-line. For example : <kbd>M-x</kbd>`compile`<kbd>RET</kbd>`make -k CXXFLAGS='-Wall'`<kbd>RET</kbd>