# How to make Emacs 's shell mode source my profile file?

Tags: bash, shell, emacs, alias, zsh

I have defined some aliases and function snippets int some of my profile files, say, `~/.zprofile`. But Emacs never reads them. There is [already a topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663396/how-do-i-make-emacs-recognize-bash-environment-variables-for-compilation) about it. However, it's not enough:

1. It cannot `source` completely `.zshrc` and would emit errors for
   `compinit` and the like.
2. Seems this approach only works for environment VARIABLES.

So in `shell-mode` or run command in Emacs(<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>!</kbd>) the effect is still different with that in terminal(emulators).

So is there any way to deal with the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create a file ~/.emacs_zsh (or .emacs_bash, emacs_sh, ...) that shell-mode will use on startup.  My .emacs_bash is simply:

```
. ~/.profile
```

Just be sure to put a newline at the end of the sourcing line or it won't get executed.

Comment: Works! BTW, could you please also show me some reference for this? Thanks.

Comment: These can also be created within .emacs.d with a slightly different naming convention: ~/.emacs.d/init_bash.sh