# emacs and python environment

Tags: python, macos, shell, emacs

I have a local Python installation in **//anaconda/bin/python**

In the command prompt

```
$python
>>import sys
>>print sys.executable
>>//anaconda/bin/python
```

but, in emacs I get

```
M-x shell
bash-3.2$ python
>>import sys
>> print sys.executable
>> /usr/bin/python
```

How can I set my path to use the desired Python in the emacs shell?

Comment: I'm not familiar with emacs so I couldn't tell you off hand, but presumably there is a way to set your `$PATH` in the emacs shell to prepend it with /anaconda/bin. Google appears to have many answers to this. It has little in particular to do with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the PATH environment variable that emacs uses.

Check out
[How do I make Emacs recognize bash environment variables for compilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663396/how-do-i-make-emacs-recognize-bash-environment-variables-for-compilation)

Specifically this:
https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell

> On OS X, an Emacs instance started from the graphical user interface
>   will have a different environment than a shell in a terminal window,
>   because OS X does not run a shell during the login. Obviously this
>   will lead to unexpected results when calling external utilities like
>   make from Emacs.
>
> This library works around this problem by copying important
>   environment variables from the user's shell.

Answer (score 0):

As demented hedgehog wrote, you need to modify your PATH environmental variable in emacs. Specifically, add this line in your `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file, depending on where your init file is.

```
(setenv "PATH"
    (concat
     "//anaconda/bin:"
     (getenv "PATH")
     )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: at Linux simply starting emacs from shell will read the current path in.