# Emacs IPython doesn't see the same environment variables as IPython from the terminal

Tags: python, bash, emacs

I just noticed that my IPython (as called by `run-python` against my variable `python-shell-interpreter`) doesn't see all my environment variables, but IPython called from bash in the terminal does. I exporting *MYVAR* in **both** `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`.

When I evaluate `os.getenv('MYVAR')` in the terminal ipython, it works. But inside of emacs nothing shows up. Why would it be different in Emacs?

Comment: Can you try to `M-x shell-command echo $MYVAR RET`? Does emacs see `MYVAR` from .bashrc at all?

Comment: IMO a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279055/emacs-and-python-environment BTW you may try python-mode.el. It would be considered a bug there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was unrelated to ipython. I was starting Emacs from my desktop environment menu (GNOME on CentOS 6), rather than from the terminal. Doing the latter resolved the issue.